# fetch user home feed from twitter in android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-feed

i want to fetch the user home feed from twitter .

I want to know the url query by which we can fetch the user home feed . Currently authorization from twitter using OAuth lib. are done .

Is there any query url like searching tweets  [twitter search feed url query](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=android)

by which we get home feed and user status.

What query should be written to get twitter home feed ??

Comment: Are you using the Twitter4j library?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are authenticated successfully with Twitter, you don't need to query a URL to get  the Timeline of the logged in user. Even if you could, I am not aware of it.

That being said, I use this to fetch the Timeline:

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

// GET THE CONSUMER KEY AND SECRET KEY FROM THE STRINGS XML
String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = getString(R.string.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = getString(R.string.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

// TWITTER ACCESS TOKEN
String twit_access_token = twitPrefs.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");

// TWITTER ACCESS TOKEN SECRET
String twit_access_token_secret = twitPrefs.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
builder.setOAuthAccessToken(twit_access_token);
builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(twit_access_token_secret);

AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(twit_access_token, twit_access_token_secret);
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

Paging paging = new Paging(1, 20);
statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);

// NOW LOOP THROUGH THE statuses AND FETCH INDIVIDUAL DETAILS
for (int i = 0; i < statuses.size(); i++) {
    String strTweetID = String.valueOf(statuses.get(i).getId());

    .... REST OF WHATEVER YOU NEED TO PULL OUT OF THE 
}
```

*Some info about instances used in the example:*

1: The line: `statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);` used in the example has `statuses` being an instance of `List<Status>` declared as a Global variable:

```
List<Status> statuses = new ArrayList<Status>();
```

2: `twitPrefs` is an instance of `SharePreferences` that I use to store the **OAuth Token** and the **OAuth Secret Key**. You will need to replace that with your own method of retrieving that data.

3: The `String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = getString(R.string.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);` and the `String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = getString(R.string.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);` are pulled from the `strings.xml`. Similar to the 2nd point above, use whatever method you currently employ to retrieve the said details.

*ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:*

If you prefer to get a **JSON** response, make this change to the above code:

```
builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
builder.setOAuthAccessToken(twit_access_token);
builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(twit_access_token_secret);
builder.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);

try {
    Paging paging = new Paging(offSet, 5);
    statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);

    try {
        String strInitialDataSet = DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(statuses);
        JSONArray JATweets = new JSONArray(strInitialDataSet);

        for (int i = 0; i < JATweets.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject JOTweets = JATweets.getJSONObject(i);

            String tweetID = JOTweets.getString("id");

            .... OTHER DETAILS YOU NEED.
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

} catch (Exception e) {

}
```